# Credit Card validation & checking

Tags: payment-gateway

HI. I see some libraries of detecting credit card # is valid or not.  However, it is based on the algorithm, not really checking with the credit card company.

is there a way or API so that I can pass in the card name & the card # and see if they are valid and match?

also, which payment getway is good?

Answer (score 4):

You can use authorize.net as payment gateway, and their API allow you to "authorize" before "capturing" the fund from a credit card. That will allow you make sure the card has enough fund in it.

Regarding name match, in authorize.net there is an anti-fraud feature where you can force the gateway to verify name, address, zip code etc. so when there is one or multiple mismatch, the transaction will be declined.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have alternative payment gateway that work in asia? Authorize.net only available for US and Canada

Answer (score 2):

Credit card numbers are validated against a check digit using the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). The Wikipedia article includes links to implementations in a variety of languages.

See also [here](http://www.beachnet.com/~hstiles/cardtype.html).

Comment: Well. what I want is not just the number. but also check against the user name.

Comment: @seatoskyhk: That's no possible without querying a card processor or card company.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the number for transcription errors (or for a really stupid forger) on your own (see [Dennis's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/221616/credit-card-validation-checking/221628#221628)). To check the credit card number for actual validity (as in: has the card been issued, has it been declared as stolen, etc.), or to check that the expiration date, name, etc., you need to contact the issuing bank (or credit card organization). You need to open an account with them (or more typically through your own bank acting as a forwarder). This is a service that you pay for. It's usually provided as part of a bigger package including the possibility of issuing credit card payments. Once you have chosen a provider, they will supply a piece of software to contact their service, and more importantly credentials for their service that will remain valid as long as your contract with them runs.

Comment: does paypal also do validation?

Comment: There is no validation service per say, you just try creating an authorization request for a low amount, 0 is starting to become standard.  Really what you do is try a transaction and see if it fails - and yes these transactions do cost money.  Why do you need to validate a credit card without charging it?